# Determine if file location is an alias in bash scripting

Tags: macos, bash, alias, symlink

Symlinks are different than aliases, although they seem to serve the same purpose (more or less/I think).  I need to be able to tell if a file is an alias, and

```
if [ -h /path/to/file ]
```

doesn't work.  Is there anything like this for aliases?  Google was most unhelpful as aliases are apparently the name for something else in bash altogether.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Finder stores the information that a file is an alias in the ResourceFork of the file. To read this metadata, I would use spotlight to determine the kind of the file; the following command will return the kind of the file, so you could then compare it in an if-statement.

```
 mdls -raw -name kMDItemKind /path/to/test.pdf          returns  PDF (Portable Document Format)
 mdls -raw -name kMDItemKind /path/to/test.pdf\ Alias   returns  Alias
```

An other way would incorporate Applescript, which is executable on the command line via osascript. To return the kind of a file, run:

```
tell application "Finder" to get kind of ((POSIX file "/path/to/test.pdf\ Alias") as alias)
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me, but got name started. Below you can find what worked for me (can't put several lines of code here).

Comment: Be careful when using this `kMDItemKind` spotlight property for string comparisons. The value is localized and may not be "Alias" for every system language.

Comment: Consider using the `kMDItemContentType` mdls property which returns `com.apple.alias-file` to determine Finder aliases independent from the user's system language.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear if you're asking about:

- aliases (a way of making one command actually run something else)
- symlink (a way of making a shortcut to a file)
- hard link (two file names both pointing to the same file contents)

The command you were trying:

```
if [ -h /path/to/file ]
```

helps you figure out if a file is a symlink or not, e.g.:

```
$ touch newfile
$ ln -s newfile newlink
$ for f in newfile newlink; do
    if [ -h "$f" ]; then
        echo "$f is a symlink"
    else
        echo "$f is not a symlink"
    fi
done
newfile is not a symlink
newlink is a symlink
```

If you mean: "how can I find out whether typing some command will run an alias", then you can use `type` or `alias`, e.g.

```
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto --format=across'

$ type less
less is /usr/bin/less
```

If you're asking about hard links, `find -inum` and `ls -i` can help, but that is a more advanced topic.

Answer (score 1):

Asmus' solution did not quite work for me, but he got me started.
Here is what worked for me (macOS 10.13 , High Sierra, assuming you execute it in bash):

```
alias=$( mdls -name kMDItemKind "$file" )
if [[ "$alias" = *Alias* ]]
then
    echo "$file is an Alias"
fi
```

HTH.

Comment: Upvote his answer ... if you are checking for alias couldn’t u just check if the file exists?

Comment: Re "if you are checking for alias couldn’t u just check if the file exists" -- what if the alias is broken?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `/usr/bin/getfileinfo` utility:

```sh
if ((`getfileinfo -aa /path/to/file`))
then #
fi
```